# How can I run my python program continuously

Tags: python, azure, google-cloud-platform, cloud

So, I've written a python program that collects data from an api every minute, stores the data in a csv file and then email it every 24 hours using the smtp library. I wrote it using Pycharm and it is running on my laptop. But, I want to know what's the easiest way to run it continuously on a cloud server(I have an azure subscription but any other way works) so that it it keeps collecting data and emailing it to me. I don't have much knowledge about cloud so any help is appreciated.

Comment: get a vps from azure free tier and use `nohup python scrypt.py &`

Comment: Unfortunately this question is off-topic here, as there's just no way to answer this objectively. You've tagged multiple clouds (gcp and azure), and both have their different ways of running code (and there are multiple ways to approach this). I would suggest starting with the docs for each cloud's services.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure I would first deploy your code on [Azure serverless](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/solutions/serverless/)

Then set up a [scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/scheduler-intro) to run the code every `n` hours!

Comment: The OP's question is far too broad, and they tagged multiple clouds. Best not to answer such a question, as their question can really be covered by them reading the service documentation for each cloud. Plus, link-only answers aren't really answers.